# fscanf read format not work

Tags: c, format, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("b3lyp.dat", "r");

    float t[13];
    double y[13];
    for(int i=0; i<13; i++){
        if (feof(fp))
            break;
        fscanf(fp,"%lf %ld",&t[i],&y[i]);
        printf("%lf %ld\n", &(t[i]),&(y[i]));
     }
}
```

I want to read data below with program above,

```
1.04981 0.043781274601002
1.06981 0.029635536304994
1.08981 0.018682198951012
1.10981 0.010554297987994
1.12981 0.004922853528996
1.14981 0.001492913057007
1.16981 0
1.18981 0.000206935596992
1.20981 0.001900993164014
1.22981 0.00489135292699
1.24981 0.009006824127994
1.26981 0.014093809840006
1.28981 0.020014492864988
```

while I always get printf as below. I want to read data into long float or double precision, 
what should be the proper way to do? Thanks for your help

```
0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000
```

Comment: Using a debugger would've helped you identify that the problem was how you were printing, not how you were scanning.

Comment: Is it a binary file? If yes then use "rb" mode to open it

Comment: Alwasy a good idea to check `fscanf()` result as in `if (2 != fscanf(fp, "%f%lf", &t[i], &y[i])) handle_error();`

Answer (score 3):

You want to use:

```
fscanf(fp,"%f %lf", &t[i], &y[i]);
printf("%f %f\n", t[i], y[i]);
```

The `scanf` functions and `printf` functions have slightly different format specifiers:

- `fscanf`: `%f` is used for `float`, and `%lf` is used for `double`.
- `printf`: `%f` is used for both `float` and `double`.

Also, the `printf` function uses pass-by-value, so you don't need to pass the addresses of the values being printed. Just pass the values directly.

If you want more information, here are the reference pages for `printf` and `scanf`:

- [fscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/)
- [printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)